# Plug.dj auto-grab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know of a way to auto-grab songs?

I want to make a playlist of songs so that I can make a playlist and listen to them. I've tried making a script but it somewhat worked, it opens the menu but it doesn't add it to the playlist. Here is my code:

```
function grab_song(){
    $(".icon-grab").click();
    $(".pop-menu ul li:first-child").click();
}
setTimeout("grab_song()", 5000);
```

The code is simple, and it will grab the song. But it will open the menu, and not grab the song. I used inspect element to try and disect the code to select the code to add it to the playlist, but so far, it just opens the menu.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm dealing with here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMkqU.jpg

I'm sorry if this is a newb question, I'm learning jQuery still.

If anyone can help please do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug is actually listening for mousedown events on the pop-menu, not click events. You would have to replace the second `.click()` with a `.mousedown()`. Also you should use `$("#grab")` instead of `$(".icon-grab")`, as it's more reliable.

A sample autograb script could look something like this:

```
API.on("advance", window.autograb = function(){
  $("#grab").click()
  $(".pop-menu ul li:first-child").mousedown()
})
```

which could be stopped again with `API.off("advance", window.autograb)`